# An explicit expression for a function defined by an integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

Can the following function
$$
F(y,p) = \int\limits_1^y\ x\frac{(x-1)^{p-1}(y-x)^{p-1}}{(x+1)^{p+1}(y+x)^{p+1}}dx,\quad
y>1, p>0
$$
be expressed in terms of known special and elementary functions?

Comment: Yes, these functions are called Appell-Lauricella functions https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.15
$$
{F_{1}}\left(\alpha;\beta,\beta^{\prime};\gamma;x,y\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(
\gamma\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\Gamma\left(\gamma-\alpha\right)}\int_
{0}^{1}\frac{u^{\alpha-1}(1-u)^{\gamma-\alpha-1}}{(1-ux)^{\beta}(1-uy)^{\beta^
{\prime}}}\,\mathrm{d}u
$$

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thanks for the comment. Indeed, one can always write $x = (x - 1) + 1$.